# Scrapy with empty content <td></td>,how i get the inside content?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have something problem when i using *scrapy* to catch all table element to csv file, i have almost done catching all data, just some table column is empty(like, `<td></td>`), does it have any ways to prevent this happened? I using the scrapy shell xxx.com and using `sel.xpath(xxx)` to get data, it didnt show the `<td></td>`, but the website frame source have. so when i using the `sel.xpath(xxx)` data to my csv file, the format will get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try the path as,

```
sel.xpath('//td/text()').extract()
```

2.Might be the owner of the website has been blocked for scrape like yell.com.

Comment: hi @anandhakumar , i know this part, just the sel.xpath('//td/text()').extract() avoid the empty content in <td></td> , btw thanks your comment.